# GPG sign all git commits without stash

Tags: git, gnupg, sign, git-stash

git 2.0 has the config option `commit.gpgsign` which will sign all commits.

This will also apply for `git stash` and will ask for the password of my gpg key.

Is ther a way to automatically sign all commits, tags,... but exclude stashes?

Comment: Does GPG not have a credential store like `ssh-agent` for SSH?

Comment: @Cupcake: there is `gpg-agent` which will cache the credentials, but since there normaly is some time between the last commit and stash it will (and should) ask again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is alias territory:

```
git config --global alias.stashq '-c commit.gpgsign=false stash'
```

Comment: Does GPG not have a credential store like `ssh-agent` for SSH?

Answer (score 7):

I like jthill's answer, just wanted to provide a slightly different option so you don't have to learn to type a new command. You can define a shell function in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
git() {
  case $1 in
    stash) set -- -c commit.gpgsign=false "$@" ;;
  esac
  command git "$@"
}
```

Now when you run `git stash` then the shell function inserts the extra arguments before calling the git binary.

Comment: I upvoted this long ago, but I do want to point out that just using $1 doesn't work if you feed any options to the git command itself, for instance you can `git -C ~/other/repo push` to run push in that other repo.

Comment: @jthill Indeed, thanks, and if that's a concern then your answer is the better approach.